# How do you filter using a custom taxonomy query?

Tags: php, custom-post-type

I am trying to use ajax to filter by category, through my custom posts, but it doesn't seem to work for custom posts.

I have created a custom taxonomy called 'image_category'.

I think I'm on the right lines:

```
$category = $_POST['category'];

$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'image',
              'posts_per_page' => -1,
              'tax_query' => array(
                 array( 'taxonomy' => 'image_category',
                 'field' => 'term_id',
                ),

           );

        if(isset($category)) {
            $args[2][1] = array($category);
                
}
  
$query = new WP_Query($args);
        
if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();

  echo '<div class="col-md-3">hi</div>';

endwhile;
endif;
```

Here's how im adding my image_category custom post type:

```
function image_category() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'Image Categories', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'Image Category', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ), 
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'Image Category', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All categories', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'Parent Categories', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'Parent Category:', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'New Category Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'Add New Category', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'Edit Category', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'Update Category', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'                  => __( 'View Category', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate categories with commas', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'Add or remove categories', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'Choose from the most used', 'text_domain' ),
    'popular_items'              => __( 'Popular Categories', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'Search Categories', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'Not Found', 'text_domain' ),
    'no_terms'                   => __( 'No categories', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list'                 => __( 'Categories list', 'text_domain' ),
    'items_list_navigation'      => __( 'Categories list navigation', 'text_domain' ),
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
);
register_taxonomy( 'image_category', array( 'image' ), $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'image_category', 0 );
```

Comment: Let me know if you need my ajax code or custom post functions

Comment: What does `$category` contain? Is that a single value, or an array?

Comment: A single value @CBroe

Comment: And we are talking about the default WP category here - and not maybe a custom taxonomy you created specifically for your CPTs?

Comment: I HAVE created a custom taxonomy called image_category

Comment: And is _that_ what you want to filter by? Then you need a taxonomy query, not a category query - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters

Comment: I've added a taxonomy query (see post edits), still not working

Comment: You added only “half” a taxonomy query. You did not specify any actual value to search for.

Comment: I cant work out what else i need to add, i've added code to this post showing how i registered my custom post type (image_category)

Comment: You need to specify what _term_ out of this taxonomy you want to filter by. The portion of the documentation I referred you to _has_ an explanation of the parameters, _and_ examples … what are you still missing then?

Comment: Sorry i think i should make it clearer, I want to filter by whatever value is inside $category

Comment: That was already clear.

Comment: Do i need a terms item in my custom taxonomy? Please i am very desperate

Comment: Yes, if you want to filter for a specific term, then you need to specify which one.

Comment: With `if(isset($category)) { $args['tax_query'] = array($category); }` you are _overwriting_ the complete `$args['tax_query']` again, that you added before.

Comment: Updated my code, i think i have getting there, i have added id to my custom type terms and have extended my args array, can't quite work out if im on the right track, any tips please im pulling my hair out? thanks @CBroe

Comment: What value are you trying to filter by, is that actually a slug, or maybe an ID?

Comment: In my filter, each button is a for a different category, i am getting the category id using this: $cat->term_id; and it works, i just need to find that same term id for the actual posts using that args array

Comment: The point of my question was about the value of the `field` option.

Comment: Listen im not really sure why i put slug there, for the life of me i cant work out how to find what category these custom posts are in, using this array. One would just use category__in if they were normal posts. Im really not very good with these arrays as you can see, any ideas please @CBroe

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters explains the meaning of the `field` parameter, so what trouble are you having with that, exactly?

Comment: Thanks i've changed the field parameter to 'field' => 'term_id', which i think makes sense, what should i be putting inside the  $args[] ? i was thinking $args[2][1] but that doesn't work (see updated code)

Comment: Your `$args` array does not have any numeric keys on the top level. You want to start with `$args['tax_query']` here - _that_ then is itself a two-dimensional, numerically indexed array.

Comment: Ok, from there how do i get the term_id? like this $args['tax_query[1]'] ?

Comment: `$args['tax_query'][0]['terms']` should be what you want to set here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = array(
              'post_type' => 'image',
              'posts_per_page' => -1,
              'tax_query' => array(
                 array( 'taxonomy' => 'image_category', 
                        'field' => 'term_id',
                       
                ),

           ),
       );

        if(isset($category)) {
           $args['tax_query'][0]['terms'] = array($category);
        }
```